# SQL Update Multiple columns with counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sql-update

We currently have SQL update statements that works for our needs and updates the `tbl_rprt` table. Below are some of the update queries, there are several others like them. I was wondering if there was another way to get this done, maybe combining all of them into one SQL statement. `#tbl_rprt` is a report of all the counts of specific flags in `wrk_tbl_flgs` for each class and room `rm`.

```
    UPDATE #tbl_rprt
    SET a_count = a.a_count
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) a_count, new_c1, new_c2 FROM wrk_tbl_flgs WHERE a_flg = 'Y' GROUP BY new_c1, new_c2) a
    WHERE a.new_c1 = #tbl_rprt.class AND a.new_c2 = #tbl_rprt.rm

    UPDATE #tbl_rprt
    SET b_count = a.b_count
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) b_count, new_c1, new_c2 FROM wrk_tbl_flgs WHERE b_flg = 'Y' GROUP BY new_c1, new_c2) a
    WHERE a.new_c1 = #tbl_rprt.class AND a.new_c2 = #tbl_rprt.rm

    UPDATE #tbl_rprt
    SET c_count = a.c_count
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) c_count, new_c1, new_c2 FROM wrk_tbl_flgs WHERE c_flg = 'Y' GROUP BY new_c1, new_c2) a
    WHERE a.new_c1 = #tbl_rprt.class AND a.new_c2 = #tbl_rprt.rm

    UPDATE #tbl_rprt
    SET d_count = a.d_count
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) d_count, new_c1, new_c2 FROM wrk_tbl_flgs WHERE d_flg = 'Y' GROUP BY new_c1, new_c2) a
    WHERE a.new_c1 = #tbl_rprt.class AND a.new_c2 = #tbl_rprt.rm

    UPDATE #tbl_rprt
    SET e_count = a.e_count
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) e_count, new_c1, new_c2 FROM wrk_tbl_flgs WHERE e_flg = 'Y' GROUP BY new_c1, new_c2) a
    WHERE a.new_c1 = #tbl_rprt.class AND a.new_c2 = #tbl_rprt.rm
```

Update
wrk_tbl_flgs has student_id and specific flags

```
student_id, class, rm, a_flg, b_fl, c_flg ....
```

Comment: So you are updating multiple different columns to exactly the same value? (count?) PS `UPDATE c_count` seems wrong, and `SET e_count = a.e_count` doesn't have an `e_count`.

Comment: Yes I messed up while editing in post. corrected. 
No not all flags are same count for each class/rm
a flag could be low sat score, ethnicity ....

Comment: You can easily combine that in a single query using `case X_flg...`

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion there is some sort of design flaw, but without the real table and column names who can say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands you can combine into one, using conditional sums as follows:

```
UPDATE R SET
    a_count = a.a_count
    , b_count = a.b_count
    --... repeat for all columns
FROM #tbl_rprt R
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        new_c1, new_c2
        , SUM(CASE WHEN a_flg = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) a_count
        , SUM(CASE WHEN b_flg = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) b_count
        --, ... repeat for all flags
    FROM wrk_tbl_flgs
    GROUP BY new_c1, new_c2
) a ON a.new_c1 = R.class AND a.new_c2 = R.rm;
```

Comment: Ah I should have just come here first. I knew it would have to be done with a case but boy was I doing it way wrong . LONG day, too SHORT a weekend . this works great thanks